# Who is collecting the Dancing Stars?

Tags: yo-kai-watch

I got a Dancing Star in my travels, and the flavour text for it says that "rumor has it, someone is collecting these". That makes me think that they serve some kind of purpose. Who wants these? What are they good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dancing stars can be traded in at the Springdale Community Center at night. An npc there will give you different victory poses for your yo-kai once you have completed his quest. The yo-kai will need to be at least a certain level to unlock specific poses. When you win a battle, your yo-kai will randomly perform one of their victory poses.